# Capybara detecting CSS ID model ID with find('')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, capybara

I am currently working on an intranet for work which will include creating invoices.

While writing tests I am using Rspec and Capybara for testing and while running a request test I want to create an invoice and add a couple of items to make sure the vat is calculated correctly.

However I seem to be having an issue where Capybara finds the first #item_price and tries to match that instead of the newly created item.

Below is some of the code in my request test.

```
...
...
# Laptop for 369.96 inc vat
click_link "Add Item"
fill_in "Quantity", :with => 1
fill_in "Price", :with => 369.96
fill_in "Description", :with => "laptop for 369"
click_button "Create Item"
page.should have_content("Item was successfully created")

find('#item_quantity').should have_content(1)
find('#item_price').should have_content(369.96)
find('#item_description').should have_content("laptop for 369")
find('#item_total').should have_content(369.96)

find('#invoice_subtotal').should have_content(308.30)
find('#invoice_vat').should have_content(61.66)
find('#invoice_total').should have_content(369.96)

# Laptop for 337.53 inc vat
click_link "Add Item"
fill_in "Quantity", :with => 1
fill_in "Price", :with => 337.53
fill_in "Description", :with => "laptop for 337"
click_button "Create Item"
page.should have_content("Item was successfully created")

find('#item_quantity').should have_content(1)
### the offending code below
find('#item_price').should have_content(337.53)
###
find('#item_description').should have_content("laptop for 337")
...
...
```

I would like to be able to add `#item_price_2` where 2 would be the item ID. When doing this and changing `find('#item_price').should have_content(337.53)` to `find('#item_price_#{invoice.id}').should have_content(337.53)` I get the exception:

```
Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError:
unexpected '#' after '[#<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x007f991889f270 @type=:CONDITIONAL_SELECTOR, @value=[#<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x007f991889f3d8 @type=:ELEMENT_NAME, @value=["*"]>, #<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x007f991889f9c8 @type=:ID, @value=["#item_price_"]>]>]'
```

Also changing it to double quotes `"#item_price_{invoice.id}"` gives me this exception:

`undefined local variable or method`invoice' for #

I'm guessing this is because I'm not using FactoryGirl so `invoice` isn't set as a method yet. I'm not using FactoryGirl in this occasion because I would like to test how the user would interact with the invoice and items forms.

What would be the best way to fix this problem? Is there a better way of doing what I am trying to do?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your guess about `invoice` not being set yet is correct. After your form is submitted you could set it:

`invoice = Invoice.last`

Then your specs should pass.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was that simple! I can't seem to get it to work. Maybe I need to go to bed and have another look in the morning but here is my show view - https://gist.github.com/140a7edded546303b609

Comment: And here is part of my spec - https://gist.github.com/4fdee18e30da12e4c3f1 - I think that's all you need?

Comment: Line 6 of your spec should actually be after the steps to fill out the form and submit data (so, around line 22). As it stands now item1 and item2 are the same.

Comment: I ended up just using `page.should have_content...` because it couldn't find any of the CSS IDs even though they were there. I may have another look at another time